# With dic.MailMerge loop wont save my doc.It Starts but it wont stop unless i shut it down

Tags: excel, vba

IM trying to crate Microsoft Letters using Excel Data but i cant close the first doc so the loop can go on . I get an Error saying :Excel is Waiting for another Program to close the Oeldb Connection.

I tryed End With after the saving but i get another error saying that there is no other with

```vb
   //create variables**strong text**
    Dim sCurrent_Path As String
    Dim recordNumber As Long, totalRecord As Long

    sCurrent_Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path



    Dim sFull_Path_of_Word_File

    sFull_Path_of_Word_File = sCurrent_Path & "\" & sWord_Document_Name



    // Start Word
    Dim app As Word.Application

    Set app = New Word.Application
    Dim app As Object                       

    Set app = CreateObject("Word.Application")  

    app.Visible = False

    //Open Word Doc

    Dim doc As Word.Document  

    Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Document")

    Set doc = app.Documents.Open(sFull_Path_of_Word_File, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sExcel_Filename As String
    sExcel_Filename = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'''

    //Loop Start
    With doc.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:="" & sExcel_Filename & "", ReadOnly:=True, 
    LinkToSource:=True, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, 
    Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data 
    Source=" & sExcel_Filename & ";Mode=Read;Extended 
    Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;", SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `" & 
    Table_with_Adresses & "$`", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess



    totalRecord = .DataSource.RecordCount
    For recordNumber = 2 To totalRecord

     With .DataSource
     .ActiveRecord = recordNumber
     .FirstRecord = recordNumber
     .LastRecord = recordNumber
     End With
     .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
     .Execute Pause:=False
     doc.SaveAs2 sCurrentPath & .DataSource.DataFields("MMID").Value & ".pdf"

   //i want to save the document here and then move on to the other data row


     doc.Close SaveChanges:=False


     Set doc = Nothing

    Next recordNumber


End With

Set app = Nothing
```

I tryed to enter End with after For-Loop but htat didnt work also
Any Ideas?

Comment: You are setting the `doc` twice. That's probably got something to do with it. Question though, why can you just use MailMerege for this instead of using it in VBA?

Comment: I need to save the documents idividually with a specific name from the data, and i have like 1000 data every month